# Problema al hacer consultas en psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

buen dia me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto en donde necesito realizar la consulta de diferentes bases de datos y para ello utilizo la extensión psycopg2 de python, sin embargo a la hora de realizar una consulta solo me muestra el primer dato de la misma, pese que hay gran cantidad de datos repetidos

```
    import psycopg2
    import psycopg2.extensions
    import sys

    def main():
        proyecto="host='localhost' dbname='api' user='postgres' password='123456789'"
        obj= psycopg2.connect(proyecto)
        cur=obj.cursor()
        cura= "SELECT * FROM public.\"pensum\" WHERE \"Id.Carrera\" = %s "
        a= 1
        cur.execute(cura,[a])
        a2=cur.fetchone()
        print(a2)

    main()
```

lo cual solo me da como resultado

```
    id.carrera |        clase
    -----------------------------
    ( 1         ,'TRABAJO DE GRADO')
```

sin embargo al hacer la consulta con SQL me bota todos los resultados:

```
    id.carrera |        clase
    -----------------------------
    1          ;"TRABAJO DE GRADO"
    1          ;"CATEDRA UDECINA"
    1          ;"CONSTITUCION Y DEMOCRACIA"
    1          ;"DEPORTES"
```

quisiera saber porque con python solo me bota un resultado y como hacer que me muestre todas los datos que requiero. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando [`fetchone`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone) que retorna solo una fila del resultado de la consulta de cada vez. Para obtener la consulta completa tienes varias posibilidades:

- Usar [`fetchall`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall):

  ```
  cur.execute(cura,[a])
  for a2 in cur.fetchall()
      print(a2)
  ```

  Lógicamente debes tener cuidado con la memoria que terminarás usando si la consulta retorna una gran cantidad de filas.
- Usar [`fetchmany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany) de forma que por cada iteración solo obtienes un máximo de x filas (5 en este ejemplo):

  ```
  cur.execute(cura,[a])
  while True:
      rows = cur.fetchmany(5)
      if not rows:
          break

      for row in rows:
          print(row)
  ```
- Usar [`fetchone`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone) pero en un ciclo:

  ```
  cur.execute(cura,[a])
  a2 = cur.fetchone()
  while (a2 != None):
     print (a2)
     registro = cur.fetchone()
  ```
- Dado que el objeto `cursor` es iterable podemos iterar directamente sobre él sin necesidad de usar ningún método:

  ```
  for a2 in cur.execute(cura,[a]):
      print (a2)
  ```